# multiply unexpected Errors

Tags: c, list, struct

I'm trying to compile this long code , but gets so many errors i don't understand, here's the code: ( I know its a very long code and many errors but i find it hard to solve it , tried for all days unsuccessfully )

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Data
{
    int i,j,n;

}typedef Data_t;

struct Next
{
    Data_t d;
    Next_t* next;
}typedef Next_t;

void printMatrix(int** m,int r,int c)
{
    int i,j;
    printf("Matrix created is:\n");
    for (i=0 ; i<r ; i++)
    {
        for( j=0 ; j<c ; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",m[(i*r)+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int calcMatrix(int** m,int r,int c,Next_t** d,Data_t** arr)
{
    int i,j,counter=0;
    printf("Enter values to the Matrix: \n");
    for (i=0; i<r ; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter values to row #%d: ",i+1);
        for(j=0; j<c ; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&m[(i*r)+j]);
        }
    }

    printMatrix(m,r,c);
    Next_t* temp1,*temp2;

    for (i=0; i<r ; i++)
    {
        for (j=0 ; j<c ; j++)
        {
            if (m[i][j] == i+j)
            {
                counter++;
                temp1 = (Next_t*)malloc(sizeof(Next_t));
                temp1->d.n = m[i][j];
                temp1->d.i = i;
                temp1->d.j = j;
                temp1->next = NULL;

                if (*d == NULL)     //add new triplet to the list
                    *d = temp1;
                else
                {
                    temp2 = *d;
                    while (temp2->next != NULL)
                        temp2 = temp2->next;
                    temp2->next = temp1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (counter!=0)
    {
        *arr = (Data_t*)malloc(counter*sizeof(Data_t));
        temp2 = *d;
        for (i = 0; i < counter;i++)
        {
            (*arr)[i] = temp2->d;
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}


void main()
{
    int r,c,**m,solution;
    int i;
    Next_t** d;
    Data_t** arr;
    printf("Please enter number of rows for Matrix: ");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    printf("Please enter number of cols for Matrix: ");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    m = (int**)malloc(r*(sizeof(int*)));
    for (i=0 ; i<c ; i++)
    {
        m[i] = (int*)malloc(c*(sizeof(int)));
    }
    solution = calcMatrix(m,r,c,d,arr);
    printf("Size of Array Is: %d",solution);


}
```

I get errors like :

```
matala0103.c(13): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Next_t'
matala0103.c(14): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
matala0103.c(30): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
matala0103.c(30): error C2081: 'Next_t' : name in formal parameter list illegal
matala0103.c(30): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
matala0103.c(30): error C2371: 'Data_t' : redefinition; different basic types
matala0103.c(8) : see declaration of 'Data_t'
matala0103.c(30): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
matala0103.c(30): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
matala0103.c(31): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'arr'
\matala0103.c(89): error C2065: 'Next_t' : undeclared identifier
matala0103.c(89): error C2297: '*' : illegal, right operand has type 'int *'
matala0103.c(90): error C2275: 'Data_t' : illegal use of this type as an expression
matala0103.c(8) : see declaration of 'Data_t'
```

Thanks so much to whoever can help me with this ! 
Itay.

Comment: 0) `typedef struct Data
{
    int i,j,n;

} Data_t;` , `typedef struct Next
{
    Data_t d;
    struct Next *next;
} Next_t;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can you post that as an answer?

Comment: simple mistakes are also present in the other.

Comment: 1) `Next_t* temp1,*temp2;` move to start of block (C89 (MSVC))

Comment: 2)There is a problem for  handling  `arr`

Comment: tl;dr. Handle one error after the other. Compile after correcting. The first one could possibly be a missing closing brace (`}`) before the reported line. C often reports follow-up errors.

Comment: it says temp1 and temp 2 have ERROR  cuz undeclared identifier , do i must give it an expression? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @ItayZaguri see my comment (1). E.g `int i,j,counter=0;Next_t* temp1,*temp2;`

Comment: amazing ! thank you so much @BLUEPIXY

Comment: now i got this error :
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open C:\Users\EiZzY\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Matala01\Debug\Matala0103.exe for writing

Comment: when `typedef`ing a struct,  the syntax is: `typedef struct optionalTagname { list of fields separated by ';' } newTypeName;`   I.E. all the current typedef statements need correction

Comment: when calling malloc()(and family of functions) 1) in C, do not cast the returned value.  Because the type of the returned value is `void *` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Because otherwise will be accessing memory at some small offset from address 0 which is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: please, for readabillity/understandability by use humans (and because in the real world it will be mandatory for documentation purposes) only place one variable declaration per line/statement

Comment: it would help both yourself and us, if there were an occasional comment that indicated the 'why' or 'meaning' of certain code blocks.  They we would not have to reverse engineer the code to try to understand what is being done and why it is being done at each point in the code

Comment: please use meaningful variable names.  such names as 'c' and 'r' are 'iffy' at best.  Much better, even though a bit more typing, to use 'numCols' and 'numRows'

Comment: when placing values into the matrix, cannot use calculated offsets from the beginning of the matrix, because that would only work for the addresses of the rows.   The actual allocated memory for the rows could be anywhere in the heap.   So when referencing a specific `row[column]` use something like: `ptrRow = matrix[row];  ptrColumn = ptrRow[column];  *ptrColumn = value;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a lot of errors:

1. In C, unlike C++, a `typedef` is undefined until it is completed. When defining `struct Next` the type `Next_t` is not defined yet. so you have to refer to `struct Next`
2. The variables `d` and `arr` are intended to get values from sub. You have to define them as pointers to structures, but pass the pointer to so the function can modify values. But you define them as pointers to pointers.
3. You don't explicitly initialize `d` to NULL, but you check it for null in your code.
4. You made confusion between pointers and arrays. Then try to use them in a mixed way adding more confusion.

See the following code, that make use of enhanced C99 and C11, to dynamically create arrays reference (I don't use my preferred method because it is not commonly liked, but also because don't make really sense here where dimensions are always unknown).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Data
{
    int i,j,n;
} typedef Data_t;

struct Next
{
    Data_t d;
    struct Next* next;    //Next_t is undefined here. Use 'struct Next'.
} typedef Next_t;

void printMatrix(int* m,int r,int c)
{
    int (*matrix)[c] = (int (*)[c])m;  //Create a pointer to an array of array of int having first dimension = 'c'
    int i,j;
    printf("Matrix created is:\n");
    for (i=0 ; i<r ; i++)
    {
        for( j=0 ; j<c ; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int calcMatrix(int* m,int r,int c,Next_t** d,Data_t** arr)
{
    int (*matrix)[c] = (int (*)[c])m;    //Create a pointer to an array of array of int having first dimension = 'c'
    int i,j,counter=0;
    printf("Enter values to the Matrix:\n");
    for (i=0; i<r ; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter values to row #%d:\n",i+1);
        for(j=0; j<c ; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printMatrix(m,r,c);
    Next_t* temp1,*temp2;

    for (i=0; i<r ; i++)
    {
        for (j=0 ; j<c ; j++)
        {
            if (matrix[i][j] == i+j)
            {
                counter++;
                temp1 = malloc(sizeof(Next_t));
                temp1->d.n = matrix[i][j];
                temp1->d.i = i;
                temp1->d.j = j;
                temp1->next = NULL;

                if (*d == NULL)     //add new triplet to the list
                    *d = temp1;
                else
                {
                    temp2 = *d;
                    while (temp2->next != NULL)
                        temp2 = temp2->next;
                    temp2->next = temp1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (counter!=0)
    {
        *arr = malloc(counter*sizeof(Data_t));
        temp2 = *d;
        for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            (*arr)[i] = temp2->d;
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int r,c,*m,solution;
    Next_t* d = NULL;    //declare as a pointer and init to NULL
    Data_t* arr = NULL;  //declare as a pointer and init to NULL
    printf("Please enter number of rows for Matrix: ");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    printf("Please enter number of cols for Matrix: ");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    m = malloc(r*c*(sizeof(int)));
    solution = calcMatrix(m,r,c,&d,&arr);  //pass d and arr by reference so they can be updated
    printf("Size of Array Is: %d\n",solution);

    if (solution)
    {
        printf("Array content;\n");
        for (int i=0; i<solution; i++)
            printf("\t%d) i=%d, j=%d, n=%d\n", i, arr[i].i, arr[i].j, arr[i].n);

        printf("Next structures content;\n");
        for (Next_t* p = d; p; p= p->next)
        {
            printf("\ti=%d, j=%d, n=%d, next=0x%p\n", p->d.i, p->d.j, p->d.n, p->next);
            if (! p->next)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Please enter number of rows for Matrix: 2
Please enter number of cols for Matrix: 3
Enter values to the Matrix:
Enter values to row #1:
0
1
2
Enter values to row #2:
1
2
3
Matrix created is:
0       1       2
1       2       3
Size of Array Is: 6
Array content;
        0) i=0, j=0, n=0
        1) i=0, j=1, n=1
        2) i=0, j=2, n=2
        3) i=1, j=0, n=1
        4) i=1, j=1, n=2
        5) i=1, j=2, n=3
Next structures content;
        i=0, j=0, n=0, next=0x00b803bc
        i=0, j=1, n=1, next=0x00b803d4
        i=0, j=2, n=2, next=0x00b803ec
        i=1, j=0, n=1, next=0x00b80404
        i=1, j=1, n=2, next=0x00b8041c
        i=1, j=2, n=3, next=0x00000000
Press any key to continue...
```

This is the version for C90 and previous compilers:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Data
{
    int i,j,n;
} typedef Data_t;

struct Next
{
    Data_t d;
    struct Next* next;
} typedef Next_t;

void printMatrix(int* m,int r,int c)
{
    //int (*matrix)[c] = (int (*)[c])m;
    int i,j;
    printf("Matrix created is:\n");
    for (i=0 ; i<r ; i++)
    {
        for( j=0 ; j<c ; j++)
        {
            //printf("%d\t",matrix[i][j]);
            printf("%d\t",m[i*c+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int calcMatrix(int* m,int r,int c,Next_t** d,Data_t** arr)
{
    //int (*matrix)[c] = (int (*)[c])m;
    int i,j,counter=0;
    printf("Enter values to the Matrix:\n");
    for (i=0; i<r ; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter values to row #%d:\n",i+1);
        for(j=0; j<c ; j++)
        {
            //scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
            scanf("%d",&m[i*c+j]);
        }
    }

    printMatrix(m,r,c);
    Next_t* temp1,*temp2;

    for (i=0; i<r ; i++)
    {
        for (j=0 ; j<c ; j++)
        {
            //if (matrix[i][j] == i+j)
            if (m[i*c+j] == i+j)
            {
                counter++;
                temp1 = (Next_t*)malloc(sizeof(Next_t));
                //temp1->d.n = matrix[i][j];
                temp1->d.n = m[i*c+j];
                temp1->d.i = i;
                temp1->d.j = j;
                temp1->next = NULL;

                if (*d == NULL)     //add new triplet to the list
                    *d = temp1;
                else
                {
                    temp2 = *d;
                    while (temp2->next != NULL)
                        temp2 = temp2->next;
                    temp2->next = temp1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (counter!=0)
    {
        *arr = malloc(counter*sizeof(Data_t));
        temp2 = *d;
        for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            (*arr)[i] = temp2->d;
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int r,c,*m,solution;
    Next_t* d = NULL;
    Data_t* arr = NULL;
    printf("Please enter number of rows for Matrix: ");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    printf("Please enter number of cols for Matrix: ");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    m = malloc(r*c*(sizeof(int)));
    solution = calcMatrix(m,r,c,&d,&arr);
    printf("Size of Array Is: %d\n",solution);

    if (solution)
    {
        printf("Array content;\n");
        for (int i=0; i<solution; i++)
            printf("\t%d) i=%d, j=%d, n=%d\n", i, arr[i].i, arr[i].j, arr[i].n);

        printf("Next structures content;\n");
        //Next_t* p = d;
        for (Next_t* p = d; p; p= p->next)
        {
            printf("\ti=%d, j=%d, n=%d, next=0x%p\n", p->d.i, p->d.j, p->d.n, p->next);
            if (! p->next)
                break;
        } //while (p->next);
    }
}
```

Please check to don't use a broken compiler :-D

Comment: super super answer ! thank you so much 
but i still get errors for this line though:
 int (*matrix)[c] = (int (*)[c])m;
error is : matala0103.c(42): error C2036: 'int (*)[]' : unknown size
and yeah i find it very hard understanding the whole pointers concept
Itay.

Comment: Thanks. As I said my code use new features of C99 and C11. The compiler you're using is not C99-C11 compliant. You cannot use that construct. You have to use the system of original code. Remove `int (*matrix)[c] = (int (*)[c])m;` declaration and instead of `matrix[i][j];` use again `m[(i*c+j)*sizeof(int)]` :-(. Or switch to a C11 compiler ;-)...

Comment: so i do have to create a ** dynamic matrix to keep on the first array the addresses , in this complier i use. or I just really lost it lol. The program shuts down after i put numbers for first row.

Comment: No. Just replace few lines. I'll add it in the solution. Wait a minute.

Comment: .the suggested answer does not cleanly compile.  1) unused parameter argc  2) unused parameter argv 3) invalid syntax for declaration of typedef for Next_t 4) invalid syntax for declaration of typedef for Data_t  5) '%p expects argument of type void * but argument is type struct Next *

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for the down vote. And for the comments. Maybe you want change your compiler...

Comment: I finally made it !! THanks Everybody !

Comment: I posted the version for pre C99. It's a pity to get a -1 for this. But if `struct Data
{
    int i,j,n;
} typedef Data_t;`
is incorrect I ask myself what is correct? :-D

Answer (score 0):

It's generally helpful to look at the first warning or error outputted, since later errors are often the result of a domino-chain of problems stemming from the first one. In this case, the first error is

> matala0103.c(13): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Next_t'

Meaning the compiler can't figure out what `Next_t` means. This is because you are referencing it the line before you actually define it; at this point in time, the compiler has no idea what a Next_t is. If you change the type to something the compiler has seen, like `struct Next_t* next;` it will work better.

Comment: This is a fine comment, but no answer.

Comment: thank you ! but it says temp1 and temp2 are undeclared